# Find "m" for which : $l=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x-sinx}{(1-cosx)^m}$

Tags: calculus, limits

So, the problem is :

> How do you determine $ m\in \Bbb R$ for which the following limit : $l=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x-sinx}{(1-cosx)^m}$ to be finite and different of zero ?

Now, my thoughts were to apply L'Hospital to it, to try to isolate m but i am not quite sure how to evaluate m . Also, m cannot be equal to 1 because that  will make the limit to be 0 ( which it cannot be because the problem says the limit has to be different of zero ) .
Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: Here L'Hopital is too weak. You need Taylor expansion. The numerator is $O(x^3)$ while denominator is $O(x^{2m})$. Hence, you need $2m=3$.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion ! I do have a question : is there another way without using Taylor expansion ?( since this is a highschool problem)

Comment: @Crostul: too weak ? L'Hospital and Taylor are essentially identical, successive applications of L'Hospital just retrieve the Taylor coefficients of the numerator and denominator. In the case at hand, it works in a single step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By L'Hospital, assuming $m>0$,

$$\frac{x-\sin x}{(1-\cos x)^m}\to\frac{1-\cos x}{m\sin x(1-\cos x)^{m-1}}=\frac{1}{2m\sin \dfrac x2\cos\dfrac x2\left(2\sin^2\dfrac x2\right)^{m-2}}.$$

Hence the denominator remains finite when $1+2(m-2)=0$ and the limit is $\dfrac{\sqrt 2}3.$

Comment: Thank you  for your answer !

Comment: I was thinking of an alternative approach and i have a question . Can this be done with Newton's binomial theorem ?  Since $(1-cosx)^m $ looks quite familiar

Comment: @Jon9: the binomial theorem would fail, as $m$ is not an integer. You need the generalized theorem, if that works.

Comment: Thank you ! The reason why i was looking for a alternative approach is because a friend gave me this problem to solve and he says he didn't even learn L'Hospital rule but still this problem was given to him as homework .....

Comment: For $m=3/2$ to work, the limit should be $\to 0^+$.

Comment: @Tavasanis: you are right. So the problem has no answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Taylor's formula.
$$
\sin x = x-\frac 13 x^3 + O(x^5)
$$
$$
\cos x = 1-\frac 12 x^2+O(x^4)
$$

so,

$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{x-\sin x}{(1-\cos x)^m} = \lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\frac 16 x^3}{(\frac 12 x^2)^m}=\frac{2^m}{6}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^{2m-3}}.
$$

The limit exists if $2m-3\leq 0$ and is nonzero if $2m-3=0$.